# Manually written function doesn't behave the same as the gamma function

Tags: r

So I implemented a function that calculates the value of the gamma function. and when I try to multiply f5(a) with a numeric I receive the error : Error in result * f5(a) : non-numeric argument to binary operator and if I instead use result * gamma(a) which is the predefined function it works just fine. It seems like it won't let me do any arithmetic operation with f5 even though it returns the same result as gamma

```
f5 <- function(a)
{
  f <- function(x)
    x^(a-1)*exp(-x)
  integrate(f, 0, Inf)

}

f6 <- function(a)
{
  if (a < 0)
    print("a is negative")
  else if (a%%1 == 0)
    return (factorial(a-1))
  else 
  {
    result <- 1
    while (a > 1)
    {
      result <- result * (a - 1)
      a <-  a - 1
    }
    result <- result * f5(a)
    result

  }
}

gamma(0.3)
f5(0.3)
f6(0.3)
```

Comment: In general, `non-numeric argument to binary operator` means you are trying to apply a binary numeric operator (here `*` but could have been `+`, `-`, `/`, `%%`, etc) to something that is not numeric. To troubleshoot, look at the type/class of what you are trying to operate on, using `class`. It is not enough to simply `print` the value to check they are numeric. Most complex objects have a dedicated printing method that does not reflect the structure of the object. Have a look at `stats:::print.integrate` to see an example yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the class of object that gets returned from `f5()`.

```
class(f5(0.3)) 
[1] "integrate"
```

This is a named list object, and you can call the specific value from it:

```
names(f5(a))
[1] "value"        "abs.error"    "subdivisions" "message"      "call"
```

You want the value component. Modifying `f6()` to the code below makes it work:

```
f6 <- function(a){
  if (a < 0){
    print("a is negative")
  }else if (a%%1 == 0){
    return (factorial(a-1))
  }else{
    result <- 1
    while (a > 1){
      result <- result * (a - 1)
      a <-  a - 1
    }
    result <- result * f5(a)$value
    result
  }
}
```